# jQuery resizable event does not end

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-resizable

I am making some interactive UI and using jQuery for resize and mouse events.

I bind `mouseOver` and click event for all elements and when I get a click, I remove the click listener (so that it does not interfere with the resizable listeners).

This works fine till here, now the selected element can be resized. starting the resize works fine, **but even after `mouseup`, the element resize event does not end, its still getting resized, with the mouse.**

What's wrong ?

The thing is located here.

http://parth.me/builderjs/index.html

The main parts are :

```
var
  inspect = true,           // to disable inspect
  selected = null;          // currently selected event

function clickhandler(e) {
  console.log('click');
  if (selected != null)return;     // if some div is already selected, then return
  if (e.which == 3)return;         // if it was right click, return
  selected = $(e.target);          // selected = the element which received the click
  inspect = false;                 // disable inspection
  selected.addClass('selected');   // add SELECTED background + border
  $(window).unbind('click', clickhandler);  // remove the click listener
  $('.selected').resizable();               // make the selected element resizable
}

$(window).bind('click', clickhandler);    //bind the click event
```

<kbd>Esc</kbd> key is bound to unselect any selection.

Comment: When I move the mouse around it works fine. when I click there is no longer any mouseOver action, is this what you intended? i don't see infinite resizing issues.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy please try it 2-3 times, it does not happen some times, but happens most of the times... and yes mouseOver is removed after the click, and added back when u press 'Esc' key

Comment: If it can help anyone, it successfully stops resizing if you click both the left and right click buttons at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @John ... also if it helps anyone, i am using a contextMenu Js : http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/ .... which is probably listening to mouse click up/down event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contextMenu(which is listening to mouseclick event) is interefering with the resize end Event(which also wants the mouseclick event). Solution :

```
  $('.selected').resizable({
    start:function () {
      $("*").destroyContextMenu();
      console.log('resize started');
    },
    stop:function () {

      $("*").contextMenu({
          menu:'myMenu'
        },
        function (action, el, pos) {
          console.log(el);
          eval(action + '(el)');
        });
      console.log('resize stopped');
    },
    resize:function () {
      console.log("resize happened");
    }
  });
```

What i did was, destroy the context menu as soon as the resize started, so its not listening to the mouseclick event anymore. and make it back when the resize event ends.

Comment: @Pheonix- I have a similar problem. I tried the solution you posted above. However, the elements become unresizable after resizing them once. Have a look here: http://autopulate.azurewebsites.net/try.html

Comment: I have the same problem but just in IE, does anyone has a different solution?