# Jquery resizabe event not ending

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, contextmenu, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using jquery resizable event along with jquery context menu. However, both seem to interfere with each other, so the resizable event does not end. I tried the solution posted on  [jquery resizable event does not end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541021/jquery-resizable-event-does-not-end) , but the elements become unresizable after resizing once. Have a look here: http://autopulate.azurewebsites.net/try.html

The corresponding functions are shown below:

```
function createContextMenu(){

$(".elmnt").contextMenu({
                    menu: 'elmntMenu'
                },
                    function(action, el, pos) {
                    if(action=='edit'){
                        $(el).attr("oldvalue",$(el).val());
                        $(el).prop('contenteditable',true);
                        $(el).mouseleave(function() { 
                            if($(el).val()!=$(el).attr('oldvalue')){
                                var elmnt_class = $(el).attr('class').split(' ')[2];
                                $('.'+elmnt_class).addClass('output');                          
                            }
                            $(el).attr('contenteditable',false);
                        });
                    }

                });
                $(".list").contextMenu({
                    menu: 'listMenu'
                },
                    function(action, el, pos) {

                        if(action=='flatten'){                          
                            var tmp=el.attr('id');
                            var t=tmp.substring(tmp.length-1);                          
                            $('div[id^="tuple'+t+'_"]:not(:first)').each(function( index ){                             
                                $(this).remove();
                            });                         
                            $('.elmnt1').each(function( index ){
                                $(this).empty();
                            });
                        }

                        else if(action=='map'){                         
                            var tmp=el.attr('id');
                            var t=tmp.substring(tmp.length-1);                          
                            $('div[id^="tuple'+t+'_"]:not(:first)').each(function( index ){                             
                                $(this).remove();
                            });                         
                            $('.elmnt1').each(function( index ){
                                $(this).empty();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                );
                $(".tuple").contextMenu({
                    menu: 'tupleMenu'
                },
                    function(action, el, pos) {
                    if(action=='concatenate'){
                        var newval="";
                        var tmp=el.attr('id');
                        var t=tmp.substring(5);                     
                        $('div[id^="elmnt'+t+'_"]').each(function( index ){
                            newval+=$(this).text();                             
                            if($(this).attr('id')!='elmnt'+t+'_1')$(this).remove();
                        });                         
                        $('.elmnt1').each(function( index ){
                            $(this).text(newval);
                        });
                    }
                }); 


}

function destroyContextMenu(){

$(".list").destroyContextMenu();
$(".tuple").destroyContextMenu();
$(".elmnt").destroyContextMenu(); 


}





$(document).ready(function () {
createContextMenu();
$('.elmnt1_1').resizable({
start:function () {
   destroyContextMenu();
   console.log('resize started');
},
stop:function () {
  createContextMenu();
  console.log('resize stopped');
},
resize:function () {
  console.log("resize happened");
},
handles: 'e',
alsoResize: '.elmnt1_1',
});


});
```

Comment: please post the corresponding functions to your resize event. also you have an error. `ec is not defined`

Comment: @Spokey function ec is for some other purpose. you can ignore it.

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found this question after running to the same issue. For the record, my workaround was to add a wrapper div, so that the outer div is resizable and the inner div has the context menu.